# Problems connecting to a server running on a (sometimes virtualized) Windows machine

Tags: python, windows, twisted, virtualization

***Sorry for using the Term Host & Guest I see that has confused things slightly. By Host I mean Client which listens on your desired port for incoming connections and by Guest I mean Server which attempts to retrieve the IP of your pre-defined Dyndns.org address. Then tries a connection. You may say that's 'backwards' but for my applications scenario that's the fitting method. Since I'm in the United Kingdom my public IP I mentioned starts with 91.

Here's two diagrams to explain if the Server connections to the Client running on the same OS.

Ubuntu - Linux

Connection over 127.0.0.1 = SUCCESS!

Connection over public IP  = SUCCESS!

---

Windows - Laptop TinyXP - Laptop Vista - VM TInyXP

Connection over 127.0.0.1 = SUCCESS!

Connection over public IP  = FAILED!

---

So the problem is Windows. I've tried the Twisted examples and again they work over local host but not via public IP on Windows so it can't be my script. It can't be the firewall as the two TinyXP installations don't have the default firewall, whilst the Vista laptop did have the default shipped one however I unblocked the process after it popped up prompting me. and thus did not yield any better results.

To forward the port I went to my Orange Livebox's configuration page (192.168.1.1) and forwarded the TCP port 4005. Just as I did for when I tested it on Ubuntu (Instead using the 4004 port) so it can't be that either. I attempted to use wireshark (Found it hard to understand). I started capturing packets on all ports, then fired up the Client followed by the Server. Resulting entries are here http://pastebin.com/ddytpydz

Alas I have no more ideas on what I can do. The twisted version I'm using is one of the latest whilst the Python version is 2.6 Any one have some ideas?

Comment: How does the guest fail to connect?  What does wireshark say is happening on the guest?  What about on the host?

Comment: I can't figure out how to work wireshark (doh!).

Comment: When you say "Host - Guest", are you referring to a virtual machine (guest) on physical hardware (host), or do you actually mean a program that connects (client) to another program running somewhere else (server)?  And what do you mean by "over public IP"?  Do you mean "using the (possibly behind NAT) IP assigned to one of the machine's interfaces", or do you mean "routed over the public internet" or something else?  What is the "right" IP address?  What is your network topology?  What do you mean by "the" firewall - just Windows firewall, or do you have a physical firewall device?

Answer (score 1):

So maybe there is some windows limitations for listenings pors. As far as I remeber some Windows can have max 5 ports open for listening. But I don't remeber exacly.

Comment: The limit is on the number of concurrent connections.   See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314882

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a firewall problem.   I would add either the port or python.exe to the approved list.

Are any of the Windows machines joined to a domain?

Comment: Yes I've tried disabling the firewall, no none of them are connected to a domain.